# Select option knockout event not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi i am using knockout to generate my dropdown box.. but i want to apply a event change on my options which are created in my for each. Nothing is getting triggered when i change my option.

code:

```
<select>
    <option value"">Please select option</option>
         <!-- ko foreach: { data: Category.Options, as: 'Options' } -->
             <option value="" data-bind="text:  Options.Name + ' ' + Options.Description, event: {change: function () {   alert('hello')} }"></option>
         <!--/ko--> 
</select>
```

can anyone see what i am doing wrong here and if so give me a example to how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: `option`s don't change, the `select` does.  Wire up the select to your viewmodel instead, you can then subscribe to any changes on that.  With knockout, you want to keep as much javascript out of your HTML as possible, that's one of the points of it - don't try to write functions inline like that, there's (usually) a better way.

Comment: [This page](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/controlTypes.html) has an example of how to bind a select.  Note how there is an [options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) available for the list of items available within a select - you usually don't need to even provide the HTML for option elements, instead have them driven by the bindings

Answer (score 0):

Check this Model:

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: selectedChoice"></select>
<hr />
<select data-bind="event: { change: selectionChanged }">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
     <option>C</option>
</select>
```

and then the ViewModel

```
var viewModel = {
    choices: ["one", "two", "three"],
    selectedChoice: ko.observable("two") ,
    selectionChanged: function(event) {
         alert("the other selection changed");  
    } 
};
viewModel.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   alert("the new value is " + newValue); 
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I've taken this from jsFiddle, but as you know it's not allowed to paste links from there.